# Validate user input against server generated data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently creating an application using asp.net MVC where I need to validate if the user has selected values among what was pre generated to him.

Simple flow example:

- The server generates a set of values: {10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 50%}
  - View shows a dropdown with the values generated to that user
  - User MUST select only one of the pre-generated values

Considering that the user can modify the html and put a random value in the dropdown - 80%, for instance. How would I limit/ prevent that behavior?

I'm currently thinking of using MemoryCache to store the set of allowed values and using the user id as key. Don't know if is the best solution. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you have the values to supply to the user when the page is rendered, surely you can access the same values when the form is submitted in the same way and compare them against the user input?

Comment: @jdurc Is not that simple because the user (as I said before) could forge the values on the form to contain whatever he wants.

So if the server has generated a set of {10%, 20%} the user could simply chage it to {50%, 100%}. And then {50%, 10%} will be posted back to the controller without the server knowing what was generated before. The thing is where to put the pre generated values to validate it even if the user modifies the html on the page.

Comment: I'm not too sure that you've understood my question. How are you generating these values for the user initially and why can you not just do the same again to compare them against the user input?

Comment: @jurc Because the values are randomly generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simpler than I thought. What I've done is basically:

1. Generate the values (eg.: 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 50%)
2. Hash the values and put it into the view model
3. Create an hidden input with calculated hash
4. Hash the posted values and check if its equal to previous hash

In my case I'm using the Compare ValidationAttribute to check the hashes, so the user can only submit the form if the values generated for him are correct.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting problem. `MemoryCache` is a bad choice though. Nothing you put there is guaranteed to even make it there, let alone stay for any dependable amount of time. It all depends on what's going on at the server. If some process needs more memory, `MemoryCache` will be the first thing to go. If the App Pool recycles, crashes, the server restarts, etc. anything in `MemoryCache` is gone. And, if you use multiple workers (web farm), then `MemoryCache` is not shared between them, leading to weird issues where the data may or may not be available depending on which worker the user lands on with each request.

`Session` is probably the best place for just persisting the values as simply as possible, but you'll need to make sure your session store is something like SQL Server, Redis, etc. If you use In Proc, you'll have the same issues as with `MemoryCache` and even StateServer can be volatile, though it's at least better than In Proc. Storing in the session also assures that the user cannot modify the values.